# How to use jquery to add a class an active link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, path, var

I am currently trying to make a navigation-menu where an active-class is applied to the anchors with hrefs that match the current url, I've found some jquery that gets the job done but on hover when I move the mouse off the item the style goes away even though I have left that active page.

```
var path = location.pathname;
var home = "/";
$("a[href='" + [path || home] + "']").parents("li").each(function() {   
        $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
});
```

Comment: Why not do this on the server side instead?

Comment: Seems like that should work, assuming `current_page_item` is defined using `a:active`

Comment: Is there anyone else that might have a deferant way of doing it I couldn't get Coles to work this is the site that I am using the menu on http://essllc.sitegov.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var aHrefs = $("li a")

$.each(aHrefs, function (i,e) {
    var href = $(e).attr('href');
    var currentHref = top.location.href;

    if ( href == currentHref ) {
         $(e).parents('li.asign-an-li-class-here').addClass('current_page_item');
    }

});
```

I think this should work.  Load this just before .  Check any other code you have that messes with the .current_page_item css class.

Forgot the parents() call.  You should assign a class name to that li element so it wont give you a false positive any further up the page.

Comment: This is the url for the site http://essllc.sitegov.com/ I am using a cms system so the menu is dynamic. I havn't been able to get any of the above option to work.

Comment: seems to be adding the class "selected" to the appropriate li element.
do 
li.selected {
   /* some css */
}